# vagrant manage hosts dhcp

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtualbox, puppet, vagrantfile

I want to automatically add/remove an entry alias to/from my `/etc/hosts` file based on the project's dirname and VM's IP address every time I run `vagrant up` / `vagrant destroy`. There are some plugins doing this but without support for dhcp.

I'm building the dirname using `machine_name = File.basename(File.expand_path('..', Dir.pwd)) + '.local'`.

The other piece of the puzzle that I'm missing is a way to get the VM's dhcp assigned IP address in the Vagrantfile and update /etc/hosts file on the host machine.

My goal is to spin-up a VM without editing it's name and/or IP in the Vagrantfile and /etc/hosts.

I'm using Vagrant 1.7.4, VirtualBox 5.x and Puppet 4.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: you said you looked at plugin but did you look at [vagrant dns](https://github.com/BerlinVagrant/vagrant-dns) it works for me using dhcp

Comment: does vagrant dns support dhcp? looking through the documentation it appears that it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've installed [vagrant-hostmanager](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager) which has a very helpful `config.hostmanager.ip_resolver` option.

Add the following code to your `Vagrantfile` to make sure your `/etc/hosts` file is updated when you run the `vagrant up` command:

```
config.vm.hostname = "add-name-here"

unless Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostmanager')
    raise 'vagrant-hostmanager is not installed!'
else
    config.hostmanager.enabled = true
    config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
    config.hostmanager.ignore_private_ip = false
    config.hostmanager.include_offline = true
    config.hostmanager.ip_resolver = proc do |vm, resolving_vm|
        if hostname = (vm.ssh_info && vm.ssh_info[:host])
            `vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I"`.split()[1]
        end
    end
end
```

Credits to: https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager/issues/86#issuecomment-107052823

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do this.

Remember that the vagrant file is ruby? write a provisioning shell script that sets up /etc/hosts and pass it as an arg in the Vagrant file the location of the file (sort of like the File.exapand above).

This way when vagrant runs the script it will generate the parameter and the provision script will pick it up and use it.

for reference: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? This is the approach I'm heading to. Also, I'm already using puppet as provisioner. Can I use two provisioners in the same Vagrantfile?

Comment: you can use multiple provisioners. re-reading your question I now see that you want to alter the parent (i.e. host) /etc/hosts not the vm one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [vagrant-dns](https://github.com/BerlinVagrant/vagrant-dns) for this purpose, it looks it does most of what you're trying to achieve (although as said by Mircea, almost everything can be done with scripting)

The doc gives an example using a private network but you can as well use the following config

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-12.04"

  config.dns.tld = "dev"
  config.vm.hostname = "test-machine"

  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

After vagrant-dns has been installed (run `vagrant dns --install`) you will be able to access your machine with www.test-machine.dev:8080

Comment: Couldn't make it work with ```config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"``` .. any suggestions?

Comment: ok it works with private_network with fix IP or public_network but not private dhcp. well the plugin is open source so you might try to hook it to make it work

Comment: @Radu, the plugin seems to have something missing indeed, I sent [pull request](https://github.com/BerlinVagrant/vagrant-dns/pull/39) and was able to make it work locally, you can review and apply this locally or wait for the merge if the plugin owner will release a new version with this fix